# Retrieving more than one value from a line in a System.Array

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api

I have a couple of api calls that are bringing me info from our Microsoft 365 estate, specifically users and license info which I am happy with and then I am pushing this data to a MySQL db.

There are some users who have more than one product license, lets say 'Office 365' and 'Project Professional'.

When I run my script, the **ForEach** captures the first license in the *System.Array* but I cannot work out how to capture subsequent licenses for users.

Api's

```
$apiUrl = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscribedSkus/'
$skus = Invoke-RestMethod -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $($Tokenresponse.access_token)"} -Uri $apiUrl -Method Get
$skus = ($skus | select-object Value).Value
#####
$apiUrl = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=displayName,userPrincipalName,assignedLicenses'
$users = Invoke-RestMethod -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $($Tokenresponse.access_token)"} -Uri $apiUrl -Method GET
$users = ($users | select-object Value).Value
```

**Current script:**

```
ForEach($item in $users){
        $itemSkuId = $item.assignedLicenses.skuId
        ForEach($plan in $skus){
            If($plan.skuId -in $itemSkuId){
            $itemSkuId = $plan.skuPartNumber
            $item.assignedLicenses = $itemSkuId

                     }
                 }  
             }

 ForEach($item in $users){
                    if($item.assignedLicenses -notin $skus.skuPartNumber){
                    $item.assignedLicenses = ("No License Assigned")

                    }
                }
```

Example output from Api call showing $users:
One has only 1 x license assigned to him, the other person has Two licenses assigned (diff products).

```
displayName                              userPrincipalName                                        assignedLicenses                                                                                                    
-----------                              -----------------                                        ----------------                                                                                                    
Joe Bloggs                            Joe.Bloggs@test.com              {@{disabledPlans=System.Object[]; skuId=cdd28e44-67e3-425e-be4c-737fab2899d3}}                                      
Joe Bloggs2                           Joe.Bloggs@test.com                 {@{disabledPlans=System.Object[]; skuId=29a2f828-8f39-4837-b8ff-c957e86abe3c}, @{disabledPlans=System.Object[]; s...
```

Essentially for every license assigned to a user it will give another skuId value.

Comment: You are showing your actual output, not the output format you want. You are already getting all licenses assigned to the users, hence the array. If you mean break out the stuff in the array to a single line, then you can use another ForLoop to do that. Loop to get al user, loop to get all skus, loop to break out the skus, [doing this as a nested loop](https://www.bing.com/search?q=powershell+nested+loop+output&form=ANSPH1&refig=958c68779fc64b4e80dfd7d8adf05908&sp=-1&pq=powershell+nested+loop+outpu&sc=0-28&qs=n&sk=&cvid=958c68779fc64b4e80dfd7d8adf05908), might be your most prudent approach.

Comment: @postanote I should elaborate further.

I am able to convert the $skuId to its friendly name by using the data from the first api call. So *skuId=cdd28e44-67e3-425e-be4c-737fab2899d3* actually equals _'Office 365'_ for example.

The issue I have is I am only able to convert the first license (skuId) on a line. If there is a second **skuId** this doesn't get processed because of this line which only picks up the first one.


*$itemSkuId = $item.assignedLicenses.skuId*